# Android Scale Animation

Tags: android

I want to animate imageviews using the scale animation the problem is that after animating on imageview how to make sure that the next one is required to start Please help me fixing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the trigger for your animations?
I don't know what is your exact case, but if you want to make a sequence of animations e.g. you have few ImageViews you want to scale one by one, it can be done like this:

1. You can define your animations and set the start offset by calling setStartOffset(). Delay time should be accordingly longer for each animation - so you have a sequence of animating ImageViews. After setting the offset you just start all of the animations.
2. Another solution would be to set an animation listener for your first scale animation - call setAnimationListener() on your animation. You will be notified when your animation ends - onAnimationEnd() will be called from listener that you have provided earlier. You could use that to start  your next animations.

But as I said, I'm not sure what is your exact case. Maybe you need something else?
Regards!

Comment: Thanks Man the animation Listener had done the Magich for me... thanks a Ton